# Disable control callbacks when setting values in code?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I've noticed that when a control such as an AutoSuggestBox has a callback, the callback is executed both when a user interacts with the control and when my code changes the associated value.

For example, if I set the TextChanged property on an AutoSuggestBox, the function is called even when my code sets the Text property to an initial value.

This is causing problems in my application in the form of both bugs and unnecessary function calls. You may be wondering how the code came to be in this state -- the answer is, I don't know. The project was handed off to me from another developer and I've been tasked to fix a number of bugs.

Although I can individually hunt down all the places in the code where this happens and temporarily remove the callback, I'm wondering if there is an easier way, for example a property I can set on the control that says, "don't call the callbacks when it is the code making a change rather than the UI".

Comment: You can register your TextChanged event right after you set the initial text , so that it will not be called twice . If you are doing multiple times set text from code, you can un-register the event , then set text , then register it again. 
You can follow this for any xaml control.
Hope this helps.

Comment: In above comment  register and unregister means , you can register event in code behind using += , instead of doing it in xaml itself.

Answer (score 0):

For the `AutoSuggestBox.TextChanged` event, the attribute of the trigger reason is provided in `AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs`, and you can judge based on this

```cs
private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.ProgrammaticChange)
    {
        return;
    }
    //other code
}
```

For other controls, you need to deal with them according to your situation.

Best regards.